# Rabbitmq. Можно ли создать очередь, которая подвязана к Direct Exchange, но при этом в нее будут попадать все сообщения независимо от routing key?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Суть проблемы, существует сервис на спринге, который закидывает сообщения в Direct exchnage без указания routing key. Есть очередь которая подвязана к этому обменнику и у нее тоже отсутвcует routing key, и эта очередь должна получать абсолютно все сообщения, которые попадают в exchange (их очень много). Появилась потребность создать еще одного слушателя (очередь), но он должен будет получать только малую часть из этих сообщений, поэтому я хочу установить routing key для этой очереди, подвязать ее к обменнику, и указывать этот key при отправке, для определенных сообщений, но в таком случае, они перестанут попадать в первую очередь. Какой подход можно выбрать для решения этой задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `Exchange` с типом `topic` и возможностью фильтровать сообщения, которые рассылаются в привязанные очереди.

```
channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");

...

// очередь для всех сообщений
channel.queueBind(allMessagesQueueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, "*");

// очередь для избранных сообщений
channel.queueBind(someMessagesQueueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, "some-key");
```

При посылке сообщений в Exchange указывайте всегда routing key. `allMessagesQueueName` будет получать все сообщения так как указан фильтр "*", а `someMessageQueueName` будут получать только сообщения с routing key равным `some-key`.

Подробности смотрите в [документации](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html).